# How do I aggregate object properties?

Tags: reactjs

I am currently building a react application and I want to combine values of every object property together. How Would I do that? Here is my code:

```
  <tfoot>
    {console.log(coinInfo)}
    {coinInfo.map((c) => (
      <tr>
        <th>Total: {numberFormatter.format(c.coinValue + c.coinValue)}</th>
      </tr>
    ))}
  </tfoot>
</table>
  );
};

export default CoinList;
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code above? Are all object properties numbers?

Comment: The code above is just the number adding itself, example: 30 + 30. The object properties are numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve:

```js
   Object.keys(coinInfo).reduce((sum, key)=>{
       return sum + coinInfo[key];
   }, 0)
```

This will iterate over all keys in the object and sum their values.